# Angular, Highchart heatmap contour chart not showing up on Firefox, works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

I have a chart that looks like this in chrome:

[image]

but in firefox:
[image]

Unfortunately, there is no error in the console.

Other chart types work on Firefox, i.e.:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no code in your question. Please read [ask]. Ideally, you should create a *runnable* [mcve] outlining the issue.

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with the sample data on some online editor?

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't reproduce this bug- when I use only the data used to create chart in jsfiddle everything works fine. Even more- the same chart is created in another part of the program (legacy web forms) and also works fine.

Comment: Try test some older versions of the Highcharts library - it might be some kind of regression